# Could not initialize class MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension - MongoDB with Spring 4.2

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongo, mongo-java-driver, spring-mongodb

I am trying to build an app with Spring 4.2, spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0 and spring-data-commons-1.11.0. The following is the exception thrown at runtime.

Kindly help. I have been stuck with this for two days.

Thanks for your help.

> Console Log

```
Oct 10, 2015 11:56:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1406)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler.init(MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler.java:37)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131)
... 42 more

Oct 10, 2015 11:56:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet spring-dispatcher
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class         org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler.init(MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler.java:37)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1406)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

> spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.8.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.whiplash.reviewr.controller" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />   

<bean id="writerService" class="com.whiplash.reviewr.service.WriterServiceImpl">
    <property name="dao" ref="writerDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="writerDao" class="com.whiplash.reviewr.dao.WriterDaoImpl">
    <property name="mongoTemplate" ref="mongoTemplate"/>
</bean>

<!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="33107">
    <!-- OPTIONAL: configure <mongo:options /> -->
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory dbname="whiplashdb" mongo-ref="mongo"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

> Jars in lib folder

```
commons-logging-1.2.1.1.jar
javax.persistence.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
mongo-java-driver-3.1.0.jar
spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Why <beans> not closed? Can you add your pom as well, since this seems to be jar dependencies issue.

Comment: @mavarazy i am not using maven for this project. I have edited the question to include the list of jars. Please have a look. The <beans> is closed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even-though it is not what you asked for but I will encourage you to leverage build mgt tools like `Maven` Or `Gradle` etc, any of those will seamlessly resolve all of the transitive dependencies which could be the issue here and increase your productivity rate tremendously 
[a quick you-tube to get you started with maven](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=al7bRZzz4oU)

[plain spring mvc app pom.xml focus on the mongo dependencies part](https://github.com/iamiddy/tin-service/blob/master/pom.xml)

[Spring boot app pom.xml focus only on the mongo party](https://github.com/IDRENE/emefana/blob/master/pom.xml)

In both cases I've used BOM to deal with dependencies versions mismatch as explained [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/02/18/maven-bom-bill-of-materials-dependency/)

Comment: i created a Maven project and the issue got resolved. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath is broken. A `NoClassDefFoundError` means that a class can't be found at runtime. I've checked that `spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar` contains `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension`. It's strange that your app can't find it, because `MongoRepositoryConfigNamespaceHandler` is also in the same JAR, implying that your class loader should have it.

Since you're not using Maven, is it possible you just have a corrupted JAR? You can find checksums and file sizes on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.data%7Cspring-data-mongodb%7C1.8.0.RELEASE%7Cjar).

Comment: I am getting the same error even after re-downloading the JAR.

Comment: I'd first confirm you really have that class in there, using something like `find . -name "*.jar" -exec tar tvf {} \; | grep MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension` in the `lib` directory. If that shows the class, then Tomcat isn't seeing the same JARs, and you'll have to figure out why, possibly deployment mechanism (which you haven't described) or some endorsed directory weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday and the only way that I found to fix this was putting the `spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar` on the lib folder of my tomcat installation, so the server loads it on startup.